# What API client is recommended for Kubernetes for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am using AKS(Azure k8),need k8s node.js client for this options

Kill pod by name
Change deployments pods count
Restart all deployments pods

I need only for this functions, witch lib is best for this?

Please also provide examples using lib for some of this functions.

Thank you

UPDATE

I liked this one `Node.js (TypeScript) github.com/Goyoo/node-k8s-client`,can you provide more information about service account and access ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full list of all the client libraries.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/

You will need to create a service account , and role binding to configure the proper permissions to do these operations from the client library.

***node.js specific libraries:***

> Node.js (TypeScript)  github.com/Goyoo/node-k8s-client
>
> Node.js   github.com/tenxcloud/node-kubernetes-client
>
> Node.js   github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client

***Basic Example ( Using godaddy client)***

```
/* eslint no-console:0 */
//
// Demonstrate some of the basics.
//
const Client = require('kubernetes-client').Client;
const config = require('kubernetes-client').config;

const deploymentManifest = require('./nginx-deployment.json');

async function main() {
  try {
    const client = new Client({ config: config.fromKubeconfig(), version: '1.9' });

    //
    // Get all the Namespaces.
    //
    const namespaces = await client.api.v1.namespaces.get();
    console.log('Namespaces: ', namespaces);

    //
    // Create a new Deployment.
    //
    const create = await client.apis.apps.v1.namespaces('default').deployments.post({ body: deploymentManifest });
    console.log('Create: ', create);

    //
    // Fetch the Deployment we just created.
    //
    const deployment = await client.apis.apps.v1.namespaces('default').deployments(deploymentManifest.metadata.name).get();
    console.log('Deployment: ', deployment);

    //
    // Change the Deployment Replica count to 10
    //

    const replica = {
      spec: {
        replicas: 10
      }
    };

    const replicaModify = await client.apis.apps.v1.namespaces('default').deployments(deploymentManifest.metadata.name).patch({ body: replica });
    console.log('Replica Modification: ', replicaModify);

    //
    // Modify the image tag
    //
    const newImage = {
      spec: {
        template: {
          spec: {
            containers: [{
              name: 'nginx',
              image: 'nginx:1.8.1'
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    };
    const imageSet = await client.apis.apps.v1.namespaces('default').deployments(deploymentManifest.metadata.name).patch({ body: newImage });
    console.log('New Image: ', imageSet);

    //
    // Remove the Deployment we created.
    //
    const removed = await client.apis.apps.v1.namespaces('default').deployments(deploymentManifest.metadata.name).delete();
    console.log('Removed: ', removed);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error: ', err);
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: What stands for 'deploymentManifest'?YAML's?

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend [kubernetes-client/javascript](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript). Within all the APIs I like raw API method most, you can see an example [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/master/examples/raw-example.js). The reasons are

1. In my experience most of the time I use kubernetes client to do the jobs that I can get result from running kubectl command. The command has a very unified format and pattern to operate different resources, such as pods, namespace, etc. And the rest APIs provided internally in k8s also follow the same pattern of kubectl command. So the key code in essence are the highly reusable and well organized.
2. Because of the above point, when APIs are consumed, it's very easy to define a unified pattern. We can handle the response, error handling, logs, etc, all the things in a elegant way. The code will look concise and easy to understand, hence easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

For node.js there are two clients:

- https://github.com/tenxcloud/node-kubernetes-client
- https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client